# why IP in different countries are in the same autonomous system?

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I notice some IPs, they are not in the same country, and these countries are not neighbors,
but they share the same Autonoumous system number

how can this happen?

Comment: Oh, it's just someone in the IANA once thought that the IP4 addresses well, very much). A further confusion occurred because of the distribution of residuals. In general wait for other answers, more serious))).

Comment: It might just be a large (Tier1) ISP that operates in many countries. And the borders do not matter at all, since network connections can span entire continents. See the atlantic cables for example.
In general, autonomous systems are not country-bound. It's just a common administration for a (maybe quite large) network.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Do not build a GEOIP database based on ASNR (Autonomous System Numbers).

Autonomous System Numbers relate to Companies, not to Countries. In most cases, the companies country is also the area where it operates. But this is not always true, look at this example:

```
aut-num:        AS6830
as-name:        LGI-UPC
descr:          formerly known as UPC Broadband Holding B.V.
descr:          ____________________________________
descr:          We provide broadband ISP services in:
descr:          Austria, Netherlands, Czech Republic, Ireland,
descr:          Romania, Switzerland, Poland, Slovak Republic,
descr:          Hungary, Germany and United Kingdom.
organisation:   ORG-UNB2-RIPE
org-name:       Liberty Global Operations B.V.
org-type:       LIR
address:        Boeing Avenue 53
address:        1119 PE
address:        Schiphol Rijk
address:        NETHERLANDS
```

I can confirm that we are seeing massive traffic from all this countries on this ASNR.

Answer (score -1):

Previous entry was in error (referring to contiguous IP addresses.)  There is a Wikipedia entry under http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_%28Internet%29 Beyond this, I defer to a network specialist.  Just reading the article make my head hurt.

Comment: No, I mean Autonomous system. They belong to the same AS but are in different countries. Since AS is about intra-domain routing, so I'm wondering how can a node in country A have the same intra-domain routing as a node in country B, while A and B are not neighbors.